# Android memory problems

Tags: android, memory

I'm not good at memory stuff in android, but the memory is too high. I'm not getting any error, but I want to optimize the performance.

**First**

I have an OnClickListener in MainActivity and it changes just the ListView content, when the user press like "Home" or "Desc" etc.
In the Listener I have an anonymus listener, I don't know if its good or not.

```
case "Mein Konto":
fullFragment.removeAllViews();
fullFragment.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_account_layout, null));
findViewById(R.id.herr).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        findViewById(R.id.herr).setBackgroundDrawable(Function.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.herr_white));
        findViewById(R.id.frau).setBackgroundDrawable(Function.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.frau_blue));
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.herr_img)).setImageResource(R.drawable.herr_blau);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frau_img)).setImageResource(R.drawable.frau);
    }
});
```

The ID *herr* is in the layout, that's why I use after inflating to avoid crash null reference.

**Second**

I have too many views in Layout XML like EditText, bla bla.
As I said, I have an navigation in App, and when the user press like "Settings", it makes a ViewGroup visible and makes invisible when the user press back. In the ViewGroup I have too many EditText etc. Not only Settings, there are a few.

**Question**

How can I improve my code?

**EDIT**

I also tried to use HPROF Dump, but I can't find the source.

Here are some example of result:

```
mContext in android.widget.ListView@Blabla
    myClass in de.demo.project.MainActivity@Blabla
        instance in Blabla
OnItemClickListener mContext in android.widget.ListView @blabla
```

Comment: may be the problem where you setting image check your image size and for more http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Maybe, the resolution of image is 1242 x 900, but I'm using Picasso library to load images from URL. Should I resize the image? If yes, how? I want to keep the ratio and the width should be minimum the width of device.